# Format Django DateField as ISO format

Tags: django, date

I'm using Django to serve up some XML. Part of the requirements is that my dates are formatted as follows: 1969-12-31T18:33:28-06:00

How can I output a DateField in Django in that format?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Introduced in Django 1.2, there is a template tag that will output what you wish:

```
{{ value|date:"c"}}
```

From the [Django template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

> c | ISO 8601 Format | 2008-01-02T10:30:00.000123

Technically, this closer to [W3-DTF](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), but close enough

Answer (score 13):

Since Django is written in Python,

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

```
datetime(2002, 12, 25, tzinfo=TZ()).isoformat()
```

Comment: Note to downvoters: The template tag was added in Django 1.2, released 2010-05-17, 2 months after this answer. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.2/

Answer (score 5):

If you look under date in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) you'll see that a variety of formats for the date are supported. Basically in a template you need:

```
{{ value|date:"some format string" }}
```

where the format string can be one of the ones defined under date on the page above or one of the custom ones defined under the now function (which includes ISO 8601 format) which is also on the page linked to above. I'm assuming that when you output to xml you do so in a similar way to a template for a normal web page.

**Update (August 2014)**

As indicated in another answer by Edgar R, as of version 1.2 onwards you can now use a built in switch to output the date in ISO 8601 format using format string: c

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by using the folowing template in my xml: <EntryDate>{{ note.entry_date|date:"Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" }}</EntryDate>

Comment: Oh, one important thing to note is that the field has to be of type DateTimeField (instead of DateField) or else the template simply swallows the value.

Comment: If he uses that format then he will get a date/time in the format: Feb. 4, 2003, 4 p.m which is not what the OP asked for (cf http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#datetime-format )

Comment: Since the original post there is now a built in option to do that as indicated by Edgar R in another post.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these docs:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-DATE_FORMAT
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ttag-now

This should be enough for you to format your date any way, you wish.